# ORA-12512 TNS:listner does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (11g)

Tags: database, oracle11g

I installed the oracle database 11g on windows 7 offline (wifi and LAN was disabled) successfully and also was connecting successfully with Form, Report builders and Toad with TNS names. After enabling LAN or Wifi when i connect is give ORA-12512 error, if i connect without giving database tns name (only username/password) it connects successfully and also after disabling the LAN or Wifi and restarting database work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DHCP?

If so, one approach to fix the issue would be set a static ip address and update your hosts file.

Another, is the suggestion by the user Street Hawk from Oracle Community, which is to install Microsoft Loopback Adapter:

1. Take control panel
2. Add New hardware.
3. Click Next.
4. Select "Yes, I have already connected the hardware" and click Next
5. From the list, scroll down and select "Add New Hardware device" and click next.
6. Select second option and click next. (to install manually)
7. From the list, select Netwrok Adapters and click next
8. Select Microsoft on the left side and Microsoft LoopBack Adapter on the Right side. Click next to install.
9. Confirm once more by clicking next.
   10 . After installing successfully, configure the IP address for that Network Adapter just as u do for the other adapters.
   But the only thing u need to care is that just give an IP and subnet mask only. Dont give any gateway or dns server ip's.
10. Then restart all oracle processes.